# how to fetch data into listview? [flutter]

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio, dart

i want to fetch the data into listview, but it keep crashing, i already fetch the api and put it in UI. how is the alternative way to fetch the api, help, i need any answer

```
class NowPlayingPages extends StatelessWidget {
  const NowPlayingPages({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(

          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColor: Colors.blue
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  List now_playing = [];
  final String apikey ='0780e6689e1189ea7b55c2a7ef7cc969';
  final readaccesstoken = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIwNzgwZTY2ODllMTE4OWVhN2I1NWMyYTdlZjdjYzk2OSIsInN1YiI6IjYyNmEzMjQ0OTBkZGUwMDBhNmUyYjEyMSIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.tmT_rASDXvRLFurM3MHnEuDxYCpfjEBJdC2hfXnULGs';

  @override
  void initState(){
    loadmovies();
    super.initState();
  }

  loadmovies()async{
    TMDB tmdbWithCustomLogs = TMDB(ApiKeys(apikey, readaccesstoken),
        logConfig: ConfigLogger(
            showLogs: true,
            showErrorLogs: true
        ));
    Map now_playingresult = await tmdbWithCustomLogs.v3.movies.getNowPlaying();
    setState(() {
      now_playing = now_playingresult['results'];
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          modified_text(text:'Now Playing', size: 26,color: Colors.white,),
          SizedBox(height: 37,),
          Container(height: 297,
            child: ListView.builder(
               itemCount: now_playing.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 167,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height:227,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(image :DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + now_playing[index]['poster_path']
                                )
                            )),
                          ),
                          Container(child: modified_text(text:now_playing[index]['title']!=null?
                          now_playing[index]['title']:'Loading', size: 14, color: Colors.white,))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please help me to find the bug, i don't really know where the error is, im new to flutter

this is the detail of how i fetch the data:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  List now_playing = [];
  final String apikey ='0780e6689e1189ea7b55c2a7ef7cc969';
  final readaccesstoken = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIwNzgwZTY2ODllMTE4OWVhN2I1NWMyYTdlZjdjYzk2OSIsInN1YiI6IjYyNmEzMjQ0OTBkZGUwMDBhNmUyYjEyMSIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJhcGlfcmVhZCJdLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxfQ.tmT_rASDXvRLFurM3MHnEuDxYCpfjEBJdC2hfXnULGs';

  @override
  void initState(){
    loadmovies();
    super.initState();
  }

  loadmovies()async{
    TMDB tmdbWithCustomLogs = TMDB(ApiKeys(apikey, readaccesstoken),
        logConfig: ConfigLogger(
            showLogs: true,
            showErrorLogs: true
        ));
    Map now_playingresult = await tmdbWithCustomLogs.v3.movies.getNowPlaying();
    setState(() {
      now_playing = now_playingresult['results'];
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you include the error you're getting in the question? Texts that appear in the debug console

Comment: there's a red box with text warning when i run the activity and it says that the activity doesn't fetch any data, so i guess the list view is work but it doesn't fetch any data

Comment: Can you show the exact code where you fetch data? I saw the api key and token thing being used but where are the http requests being handled?

Comment: i fetch it on container, you can see it on below side of the code, inside the Widget build

Comment: I think you need to wait for the fetch to complete, till then show a circularProgressIndicator and when data fetched setState that progressIndicator to off